# Firebase Push Notification received when sending to specific topic but not to all devices

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

In Firebase, I am struggling with iOS push notifications. It is not a certificate issue. I have configured the device to receive push notifications on production (downloaded from the App Store). I also put a hidden feature in the app where, if you click a hidden button, you subscribe to a firebase "testing" topic.

For some reason, my device will get the notification when I send to the "testing" topic, but if I send the notification to all devices indiscriminately, the notification will not be received. The same is also true if I send just to my FCM using the "Send Test Message" feature in the console.

Is there a reason why this might be the case?

Comment: In the case that you send "to all devices indiscriminately", is everything still the same on the mobile side? Meaning, you still press the hidden button (so the subscribing to the firebase testing topic is still happening?). If besides the subscription to the firebase testing topic, you are doing anything else only after pressing the hidden button (for example, sending the device token to firebase, setting a firebase delegate, etc.), then that might explain it?

Comment: So nothing else changes. When we send "indiscriminately," I should be sending to every single device that has an FCM. It really seems to me like a Firebase bug, but I'm doubtful that anything so glaring would make it to production there. But I can't for the life of me see why these notifications are not arriving.

Comment: I understand what you mean about indiscriminate sending, and it worked in the past when I tried it. Hence I was wondering if perhaps your app was missing something in the case with the indiscriminate sending, besides not subscribing to the test topic. But if nothing else changes, I don't know what could be the problem.